# Derivative of Fourier transform: does the property exist

Tags: fourier-analysis

There is a known property regarding the Fourier transform of a derivative.

But what about instead the derivative of a Fourier transform. Do we have properties for that that help us calculate it?

Comment: That's the Fourier inversion theorem.